# How to iterate through a char ** variable

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, rpc

I'm running a small rpc program/ using an rpc framework that takes a `char[]` from the client file and sends it to the server that enumerates the integers in the string.

I have a file `client.c` that takes user input and passes it to an external function in a header file.

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include "getNumInt.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    CLIENT *cli;
    char *server;
    server = argv[1];

    cli = clnt_create(server, GETNUMINT, GNUMINT, "tcp"); //creates a client handle
    /*does some check for whether the client connected*/
    char command[256];
    int *numInt;
    fgets(command, 256, stdin); 
    numInt = enumints_1(&command, cli); //segfaults here according to backtrace
    return(0);
}
```

The function `enumints_1` is defined in my server stub `server.c` as:

```
int *enumints_1(msg, req)
    char **msg; struct svc_req *req;{
    printf(*msg);
    static int numDigits = 0;
    char msgcopy[256];
    strcpy(msgcopy, *msg);
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i<strlen(msgcopy); i++){
        if(msgcopy[i] >= '0' && msgcopy[i] <='9'){
            numDigits++;
        }
    }
    return(&numDigits);
}
```

My main issue is how I iterate through the `char **msg` as that is likely why my program is segfaulting.
`command` is just a string taken from user input and then passed by reference to the `enumints_1` function. 
Since it is a pointer to a point I assumed that I could just `strcpy` or `memcpy` to copy the string to a char array, but that doesn't work.

also my `.x` file:

```
struct intStringPair{
    int numInts;
    char msg[256];
};

program GETNUMINT{
    version GNUMINT{
        int ENUMINTS(string) = 1; //string considered char * the rpc generated file makes it so enumints_1 then has to take char **
        int WRITEMESSAGE(intStringPair) = 2;
    } = 1;
}= 0x20000001;
```

Comment: `command` is not a pointer. So `&command` is not a pointer-to-a-pointer.

Comment: Yikes.  Why are you using the ancient untyped function interface for `enumints_1`? A normal prototype is much less error prone.

Comment: @Gene they're auto generated by rpcgen from the .x file. edit: I misunderstood, the prototype is unfortunately what's needed for rpcgen to generate the `.h` which is where `enumints_1` comes from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @user3386109 said:

> command is not a pointer. So &command is not a pointer-to-a-pointer

so assigning &command to msg is not valid (and my compiler doesn't even compile it)

When I compile this code:

```
// my set up code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct svc_req {};
typedef struct svc_req CLIENT;
struct svc_req *clnt_create(const char *, int, int, const char*) {return 0;}
int GETNUMINT=0, GNUMINT=0;

// your code verbatim

int *enumints_1(char **msg, struct svc_req *req){
    printf(*msg);
    static int numDigits = 0;
    char msgcopy[256];
    strcpy(msgcopy, *msg);
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i<strlen(msgcopy); i++){
        if(msgcopy[i] >= '0' && msgcopy[i] <='9'){
            numDigits++;
        }
    }
    return(&numDigits);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    CLIENT *cli;
    char *server;
    server = argv[1];

    cli = clnt_create(server, GETNUMINT, GNUMINT, "tcp"); //creates a client handle
    /*does some check for whether the client connected*/
    char command[256];
    int *numInt;
    fgets(command, 256, stdin); 
    numInt = enumints_1(&command, cli); //segfaults here according to backtrace
    return(0);
}
```

The compiler says:

```
<source>: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
<source>:34:25: error: cannot convert 'char (*)[256]' to 'char**'
     numInt = enumints_1(&command, cli); //segfaults here according to backtrace
                         ^~~~~~~~
<source>:10:24: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int* enumints_1(char**, svc_req*)'
 int *enumints_1(char **msg, struct svc_req *req){
                 ~~~~~~~^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

What you can do instead is make a pointer to the array and then pass the address of that:

```
// my set up code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct svc_req {};
typedef struct svc_req CLIENT;
struct svc_req *clnt_create(const char *, int, int, const char*) {return 0;}
int GETNUMINT=0, GNUMINT=0;

// your code verbatim
int *enumints_1(char **msg, struct svc_req *req){
    printf(*msg);
    static int numDigits = 0;
    char msgcopy[256];
    strcpy(msgcopy, *msg);
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i<strlen(msgcopy); i++){
        if(msgcopy[i] >= '0' && msgcopy[i] <='9'){
            numDigits++;
        }
    }
    return(&numDigits);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    CLIENT *cli;
    char *server;
    server = argv[1];

    cli = clnt_create(server, GETNUMINT, GNUMINT, "tcp"); //creates a client handle
    /*does some check for whether the client connected*/
    char command[256], *command_pointer=command;
    int *numInt;
    fgets(command, 256, stdin); 
    numInt = enumints_1(&command_pointer, cli); //segfaults here according to backtrace
    return(0);
}
```