# replace first vowel of each word / iterate through char * string / append each word in string [c]

Tags: c, string, pointers

my objective is to change the first vowel of each word in a sentence into 'i' and move the initial consonant cluster (if there is) to the end of the word and add ee.

for example:

- string = "flower yellow"
- translated string = "iwer-flee illow-yee"

so far, the code i have rn is able to split the original string into words so that the strchr function finds the vowel in each word and replace it into 'i'. But the vowel being replaced is not the first vowel. Instead, it only follows the order of vowels listed in the vowels array.

- string: flower yellow
- translated string: flowir yillow

it should be fliwer yillow.

```
void englishToMatte(char englishSentence[], char matteSentence[])
{
    char** word = splitIntoWords(englishSentence);
    char *p;
    int vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    int i;
    char** it;
    char dest[100];

    for(it=word; it && *it; ++it){
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if((p = strchr(*it, vowels[i])) != NULL){
                *p = 'i';
                break;
            }
        }
        strcat(dest, *it);
        strcat(dest, " ");
        free(*it);
    }
    /*puts(dest);*/ /*for debugging*/
    strcpy(matteSentence, dest); 

    free(word);
}
```

I think I should iterate through the *it string from start to end or replace the if condition into a switch case instead but i don't know how i would be able to include strchr in the switch parameter. I know there must be an answer to this already but so far I only found too specific answers like this:
[How to iterate through a char ** variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913444/how-to-iterate-through-a-char-variable)

or c programs that gives the same undesired results:
https://quescol.com/interview-preparation/replace-first-vowel-program-in-c

i know this is a fairly easy problem to solve but i am an absolute noob.

Comment: You iterate over your vowel array. Therefore you stop if you find the first vowel from that array. You shall stop when you find first vowel of your string. That means you must iterate over your string instead over your vowel array. That is what is done in your second link. It should find the correct character but you must adapt the action to your needs.

Comment: A string is not `char**` type. Your string is not pointed to by `it` but by `*it`. What about `for(int i=0; (*it)[i]!=0; i++){ ... }` for a start? Or you could add `char *myString=*it;` and then deal with `myString` instead of `*it`

Comment: @Gerhardh i did both of what you suggested and modified the second link a bit and it worked. thanks sm. edit: deleted my initial comment before u replied. apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should approximate what you seem to want. Cannot be sure about the inserted hypen, or not.

Count the words, allocate space for result, process each word according to location of first vowel (if present in "word") building output result. Note: this will not account for multiple spaces separating words in original.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *smpl = "Quick brown foxes jump over flower yellow & Unicorns";
char *wordSep = " ";

int main() {
    int len = strlen( smpl );
    printf( "Orginal string: '%s' (%d chars)\n", smpl, len );
    
    // Count the words in the "sentence"
    char *pBuf = strdup( smpl );
    int nWord = 0;
    for( char *cp = pBuf; (cp = strtok( cp, wordSep ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL )
        nWord++;
    printf( "%d \"words\"\n", nWord );
    strcpy( pBuf, smpl); // reload

    // create output buffer large enough for expansion.
    char *oBuf = (char*)calloc( len + nWord*4 + 1, sizeof(char) );
    // calloc NEVER returns null pointer

    char *at = oBuf;
    for( char *pWord = pBuf; (pWord = strtok( pWord, wordSep ) ) != NULL; pWord = NULL ) {
        char *init = pWord; // beginning of word
        char *vwl1 = strpbrk( init, "AEIOUaeiou" ); // first vowel of word

        if( vwl1 == NULL ) { // all consonants!
            at += sprintf( at, "%s ", init );
            continue;
        }
        if( vwl1 == init ) { // eg: "Unicorn"
            *at++ = "iI"[ isupper( *vwl1 ) ]; // 'i' matching the case
            at += sprintf( at, "%s-ee ", init + 1 );
            continue;
        }
        *at++ = "iI"[ isupper( *vwl1 ) ]; // 'i' matching the case
        *vwl1 = '\0';
        at += sprintf( at, "%s-%see ", vwl1 + 1, init );
    }

    puts( oBuf );
    free( oBuf );
    free( pBuf );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Orginal string: 'Quick brown foxes jump over flower yellow & Unicorns' (52 chars)
9 "words"
iick-Qee iwn-bree ixes-fee imp-jee iver-ee iwer-flee illow-yee & Inicorns-ee
```

As an exercise, work out how to make the 'i' match the case of uppercase 'Q' at the start of the sentence (and make the relocated 'Q' lowercase...)

Answer (score 0):

in case whoever's reading this have the same problem, here's the portion of the code (much thanks to gerhardh)

```
dest[100] = " "; //initialize string
//see main post above for unmentioned variables 

for(it=word; it && *it; ++it){
    myString=*it;
    for(int i=0; myString[i]!=0; i++){
        if(myString[i]=='a' ||myString[i]=='e' ||myString[i]=='i' ||myString[i]=='o' ||myString[i]=='u'){
            myString[i] = 'i';
            break;
        }
    }
    strcat(dest, *it);
    strcat(dest, " ");
    free(myString);
}
```

now the remaining problem is to append the initial consonant cluster to end of the word. will be updating this when i find the solution.

Comment: `(*it)[i]!=0` that should be `myString[i]` then. Also `strcat(dest, myString);`and `free(myString);` And in your original code you do not initialize `dest`. Using `strcat` with unitialized memory causes undefined behaviour.